# Access only filtered values in a MS Access table

Tags: ms-access, filtering

Is it possible to get the values from rows in an Access table that are showing after the filter is applied?

Example as requested:

I have a table in which employees fill in project tasks, hours on the project etc.
It is made as a table on a form. The columns has limited choices in Initials, Project number, etc. People like to sort the table by the built in filter function in access tables and queries. I filtered so only the project LT1075 is shown in the example.

How can i get those 4 rows as a recordset or something similar? I need to get the values in all hour fields. I need also to copy only those 4 lines in VBA and do stuff to it (Functions wanted by people). But when i use the DAO, i get all rows in the "Unfiltered" table.

[image: Example]

How do i get only the rows visible?

In excel, there is a simple function, something with cells_visible but i cant find a pardon to Access.

Best Regards, Emil.

Edit, tryouts:

```
Public Sub Test1_Click()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
While Not rs.EOF
    ' Do calculation stuff on record.
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

End Sub
```

It is put on the "Test 1" button in the figure above.

I get the error: "Runtime error 7951 - You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the RecordsetClone property"

I have a clue that it does not work because of the Me.* function? Since the table is in some sort of subform. But i see only one form in the Navigation panel. (Hidden are also showed).

Comment: I think you will definitely want to expand on what you are looking for.  The answer is almost certainly yes but I'm really not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have added an example, I hope it is sufficient :)

Comment: It is 100% clearer, you are basically looking to gain access to a Recordset that is filtered the same as the form is filtered correct?

Comment: Exactly! I need it in VBA. But some workaround would be okay as well. I tried doing the filter on a query, followed by an append to a table, but the append does not "see the filter". Any suggestions? I dont want the filter to be applied from VBA, because the users wants to set the filter by clicking as usual in excel/access.

Comment: But of course if VBA somehow can "Read" the filters set by the user, it is okay to filter with VBA, as long as they don't have to set the filter 2 places.

Comment: It sounds like your main form is unbound and your data is in a subform. If so, and the button is on the main form, then `Me.RecordsetClone` is not a valid reference because the main form does not have a Recordset (Row Source). In that case you'll need to take the RecordsetClone of the subform.

Comment: Yes, i suspect that too, but how do i do that? Formname.RecordsetClone ? I tried what i though was the formname of the subform, but it didnt work.

Comment: You use: Set rs = Me!NameOfSubformControl.Form.RecordsetClone.

Comment: BANG, gustav. Just what i needed! No error. I try and see if i can continue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RecordsetClone of the form:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
While Not rs.EOF
    ' Do calculation stuff on record.
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

And you can add records to a recordset:

```
Public Sub CopyRecords()

    Dim rstSource   As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstInsert   As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld         As DAO.Field
    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim lngLoop     As Long
    Dim lngCount    As Long

    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblStatus"

    Set rstInsert = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    ' rstSource can be any recordset, here the RecordsetClone of the form.
    Set rstSource = Me.RecordsetClone

    With rstSource
       While Not .EOF
           With rstInsert
               .AddNew
               For Each fld In rstSource.Fields
                   With fld
                       If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                           ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
                       ElseIf .Name = "Total" Then
                           ' Special cases.
                           ' Insert default job code.
                           rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = 0
                       ElseIf .Name = "PROCESSED_IND" Then
                           rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = vbNullString
                       Else
                           ' Copy field content.
                           rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value
                       End If
                   End With
               Next
               .Update
           End With
           .MoveNext
        Next
        rstInsert.Close
        .Close
    End With

    Set rstInsert = Nothing
    Set rstSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. Why go through the recordset when you have a form? Dsum is also an option. Row by row is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Dsum could definitely work for the `get the values in all hour fields` part but not really the `copy only those 4 lines in VBA and do stuff to it` part.  It seems like he wants a Recordset containing the forms filtered Recordset for other purposes anyway.

Comment: @Fionnuala: It is. The records are in memory so it is very fast. Any other method will retrieve the records once more.

Comment: @NewD you can `SELECT Sum(Field)..` There are a dozen ways to get the data that are not RBAR

Comment: The whole point is that the user is going for a bad approach to the problem.

Comment: @Fionnuala I agree that the `While Not rs.EOF` part of this answer isn't needed.  Though I do think the way to access the Recordset as OP had requested is correct.  Also, I learned a new term today, thanks Fionnuala :-)

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for fast response. I can not use the DAO on a Clone. I get the error: "Runtime errlr 7951" "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the RecordsetClone proterty". I dont know this function so i cant see the error!

Comment: @Fionnuala How do you suggest the approach? It is more like a huge log file than actual data storage, so it is a bit off access's purpose.

Comment: @EmilOlsen Can you post your attempted code in the main body of your question and also let us know where you are putting that code within your project.

Comment: @Newd Please see the question again and see if that is enough description.

Comment: >  I can not use the DAO on a Clone.

Yes you can, in fact only DAO can be used here. But the Me.RecordsetClone can, of course, only be created where the recordset is, and that is in the form.

Comment: @EmilOlsen See what Gord said in his comment.  The "Me" can only be used to reference the form class that your code is currently running on.

Comment: Ye, i had that idea, but cant i point to something else than "Me"?

Comment: @EmilOlsen Yes you should be able to do something like `Forms.FormName.RecordsetClone` there are probably a dozen different ways you can reference forms in VBA.  That was one of the hardest things for me to catch onto.

Comment: Yes, gustav handed me the one, similar to yours!

Comment: Sorry for my dumb questions, i have not seen these before. Now that i expect to have the records, how is the data stored? I can see the "headlines" with the Field.Name, but can i store all of this to a table?

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: With a copy and paste and 2 small edits, it worked great! I have added an edit to your code, since it was needed to run. (Change next to wend) Thanks a lot Gustav, man of the day!

Comment: Hmm ... it really should be For/Next or While/Wend.

Comment: Now I found the edit. It is correct. 

For some reason I can't approve it.

It is beyond me why some reject the edit.

Comment: @Gustav I have troubles again with this, struggling for an hour now. I have a form with the button that does the rs.RecordsetClone. The desired recordset is in the auto named form "t_BASE_subform1". I do the command: Me!Forms.t_BASE_subform1.RecordsetClone, but i get errors. I tried different variants, but I cant manage to get it working....

Comment: If it is a subform, it should be: Me!t_BASE_subform1.Form.RecordsetClone. If it is another form: Forms.t_BASE_subform1.RecordsetClone

Comment: Ah. yes, how could i mix that up... Can you maybe add that as a comment to your answer? Since i guess most people put in tables as subforms (from what i can read) :)

Comment: OK. Done. Source can be any recordset.

Comment: @Gustav Hi again Gustav. I have a minor issue that i can think of several ways to solve - But none good. The code you provided works excellent, but is it not possible to edit a record? When i do a "rstSource!Field1 = 0" it can not change it. I have a function where i need to change fields in a column for only the shown values. Is this not possible?

Comment: After an rstSource.Edit it should be possible. That's to tell without the code and context. You should open a new question with some more info.